# Repeated "Tabs" when editing contacts

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I am using Android 6 on a Samsung J7.

When I edit a contact there are several "Tabs" that can hold information, e.g., DEVICE, VIBER, WHATSAPP, etc.

For some contacts, I see two or three DEVICE Tabs (which seems puzzling to me), and two WHATSAPP Tabs (equally puzzling).

[image]

**Why is this, and how can I get rid of repeated Tabs? (I suspect I would like to do this, but I am not sure)**

Morevoer, for one contact (say, George T.), one of the WHATSAPP Tabs holds a phone number that is not shown as George T. in Whatsapp itself. On the contrary, this phone number shows both in Contacts - DEVICE Tab, and in Whatsapp, as belonging to John W. (the number belonged to George before, but not anymore).

**WHy is this, and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned wether there are two numbers saved under the same name, or not

If you have two numbers saved under the same name, all you have to do is unlink them.[image]

In the above screenshot you'll see that i saved two numbers on my phone and then i linked them together and in that case when editing this contact I'll have two tabs for Google contact and two tabs for WhatsApp. This also explains why gorge is in the wrong place - because you have him saved twice.

To un-link them, simply press the "link" icon which appears under the orange envelope. And press on the minus.

Comment: It worked. I still do not know how this appeared in the first place...

Comment: You linked them at some point by mistake or on purpose. Happens to the best of us. Glad it worked